# Create custom JSON string from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have an external JSON file and for internal use in the web application I have to create a custom and separte JSON string with all selected objects in the main JSON from the external Server.

the output string should look like this, but with more objects:

```
{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [78.454, 22.643]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {}}
```

the jquery code to create the string looks like this:

```
$.getJSON(getshowObjectReportExtern, function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, value) {

// loop html table

}   

var llrealTimeObj = {
geometry: {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
        { // loop from here
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [ value.latitude_mdeg, value.longitude_mdeg]
            },
        properties: {
            Number: value.objectno,
            Plate: value.objectname,
            Location: value.postext_short
            }
        }, // till there
    ]
  }
}


var llrealTimeJSONString = JSON.stringify(llrealTimeObj);
    console.log(llrealTimeJSONString);

});
```

to create the string for each single object works fine, but for now the problem is, that I don't know how to create a single string which contains all selected objects from the external JSON.

has anybody any advice for me? thanks in advance!

edit:
the final output should look similar like this, but with the objects from my main JSON file.

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -22.054688930511475,
      29.53522956294847
    ]
  },
  "properties": {}
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -22.933595180511475,
      19.642587534013032
    ]
  },
  "properties": {}
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -25.394532680511475,
      28.76765910569123
    ]
  },
  "properties": {}
}
  ]
}
```

link to the online editor: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geojson/

Comment: What do you want to serialize? Can you show an example output?

Comment: {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[88.123,12.123]},"properties":{"Number":"103","Plate":"X-XXXXX","Location":"XYZ"}}]}

this is the output of one object, but there are many more and for know I have hundrets of these strings.

Comment: And what is the input? How do we know which objects you want to include in the output

Comment: these are the selected objects in the main JSON string from the external server:
latitude_mdeg,
longitude_mdeg,
objectno,
objectname,
postext_short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a tip from a colleague to create the string.
see the solution below:

```
    $.getJSON(getshowObjectReportExtern, function(data) {
    var vehicleListData = '';
    var tmpLlrtArr = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {

        // loop html table

        var tmpLlrtObj = {};
        tmpLlrtObj.type = 'Feature';
        tmpLlrtObj.geometry = {};
        tmpLlrtObj.geometry = {};
        tmpLlrtObj.geometry.type = 'Point';
        tmpLlrtObj.geometry.coordinates = [(value.longitude_mdeg * 0.000001).toFixed(6), (value.latitude_mdeg * 0.000001).toFixed(6)];
        tmpLlrtObj.properties = {};
        tmpLlrtObj.properties.VNumber = value.objectno;
        tmpLlrtObj.properties.Plate = value.objectname;
        tmpLlrtObj.properties.Position = value.postext_short;

        tmpLlrtArr.push(tmpLlrtObj);

    });


    var llrealTimeObj = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": tmpLlrtArr
    }


    var llrealTimeJSONString = JSON.stringify(llrealTimeObj);
        console.log(llrealTimeObj);


    $('#vehicleList').html(vehicleListData);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is the array of JSONs that is brought from external source.

```js
//jsonData is the external data I get from server
        var jsonData =
            {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [
                                -54.9904990196228,
                                -7.88514728342433
                            ]
                        },
                        "properties": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [
                                -54.9026083946228,
                                -13.752724664396975
                            ]
                        },
                        "properties": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [
                                -49.7170615196228,
                                -16.214674588248542
                            ]
                        },
                        "properties": {}
                    }
                ]
            };

        //My custome object
        var llrealTimeObj = {
            geometry: {
                type: 'FeatureCollection',
                features: []
            }
        };

        //Loop through external data
        $.each(jsonData.features, function (i, node) {
            llrealTimeObj.geometry.features.push({
                type: node.type,
                geometry: node.geometry //Add any more properties that you like here.
            });
        });

        var llrealTimeJSONString = JSON.stringify(llrealTimeObj);
        console.log(llrealTimeJSONString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry, but this didn't work for me :(

i get the external JSON with $.getGJSON().
the orignial string contains: objectno, objectname, objectclassname, objectclassname, lastmsgid, lastmsgid, msgtime, longitude, latitude, postext, postext_short and a few more.

my goal is to create a single custom JSON string with the selected objects and items from the JSON string which i recieve from the server.

Comment: Does it mean, you have the whole JSON data with you.. but you want to loop through the features and select only few properties and create your own json?